# Wireless Keeps Setting Manual DNS Server

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have a Windows 7 Professional laptop.

At work, I connect via a wireless link that issues DHCP parameters.  During one period, I needed to use a DNS server that was not the one issued by DHCP so that I could do testing with a new AD server.  Now everything is consistent again, and I just want to use the DHCP issued parameters.

So I have brought up my network interface and clicked "Use DNS Server Provided By DHCP" (or whatever it says).

But the problem is: if I power up my laptop on the work network, then take it somewhere else where I want to use the wireless, I find that the DNS server has once again been hard-coded to the temporary server I put in.  Which won't work in these other environments.  So I have to once again open the network interface and click "Use DNS Server Provided By DHCP".

Why does the computer remember this hard-coded setting, and how can I prevent it from remembering again?

Comment: I feel your pain. http://superuser.com/questions/443182/windows-keeps-using-a-preferred-dns-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incidentally, I rebuilt this laptop due to this and other weirdness and the rebuilt OS does not suffer from this problem.