# Static DNS servers keep defaulting windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns

I'm using Google's DNS servers for my Wireless and LAN connections. However, every couple of hours the DNS server seems to be resetting and the static DNS server values are removed.

The below user had what seems to be the same problem, but they solved it by reformatting their computer, which is not something I'm ready to do.
[Wireless Keeps Setting Manual DNS Server](https://superuser.com/questions/278594/wireless-keeps-setting-manual-dns-server)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: When the DNS settings are getting reset are they getting set to a different static server or are they getting set to dynamic?

Comment: Does this happen on multiple devices, and are we talking personal or work pcs?

Answer (score 0):

Need save/restore settings GUI?:

[NetSetMan 3.5.3](http://www.netsetman.com/)

> Are you tired of manually changing your location-based network and
>   system configuration on your laptop or computer every day?
>
> Then NetSetMan is your solution. It will do the work for you. Switch
>   between configuration profiles for different locations instantly!

Free DHCP + DNS Server at Windows 7? :

[Dual DHCP DNS Server](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dhcp-dns-server/)